# I cannot close Userform in another Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have created Userform1, where  Userform2 (in VBA written calendar) will be opened after you click on TextBox1. You choose the date then you can close the calendar

Fun fact:
in 32 bit MS Office I can close Userform2 without any problem. it runs normal
in 64 bit MS Office I cannot close Userform 2 and the process will not continue.

`.Hide` and `Unload Userform2` or `Unload Me` do not work.

I have read about this issue but there were no solution.

Comment: There are some constants that should be declared differently between 32 and 64 bit versions. Please share your code with us so we can check.

Comment: You might want to read through the following article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview Furthermore, Please update your post with all relevant code (including the location of the code). Without your code there is little more but quessing that we can do to help.

Comment: You are saying that you read about this "issue" but there was no solution. Could you please reference the article you read? Is this maybe the article you are referencing: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84e51bf8-cda5-4b8d-b134-d8b4967bfd70/cannot-close-workbooks-opened-via-user-form-macro?forum=exceldev If so, there is a workable solution to the "issue".